# How to show array of integer numbers in a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have C# application that make some random number and push it into the array.

How can I show items which are kept in an array on my listview in a single column

when I want use for loop for getting number it makes error

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();

d = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);     

int[] TimeRand = new int[d];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    TimeRand[i] = rand.Next(1, 100);
}
//i use this code to show but got error
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    listview1.Items.Add(TimeRand[i]);       
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't write what error you got it can be one of two problems with your code:

- listview1 is not the correct name of the listview, since the default is listView1 (notice the capital V)
- The method Items.Add accepts only strings and you are sending it an int

This should solve your problem:

```
listView1.Items.Add(TimeRand[i].ToString());
```

Comment: so an other question
how to show numbers in one columns
for example randoms columns

Comment: @b1ack-c0de First don't forget to mark this as the correct answer so other people who come here can solve similar problems. As for the new question I think this will solve tour problem: `listView1.View = View.Details;`    `int columnSize = 50;`    `listView1.Columns.Add("Column 1", columnSize, HorizontalAlignment.Left);`    `for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {`    `listView1.Items.Add(TimeRand[i].ToString());`    `}`  **I swear I tried to put this in code but the backticks aren't working**